# Javascript infinite loop when adding to a ul list

Tags: javascript

I'm making a snake game and im trying to add a leaderboard for all the current snakes playing in a list.

This is the js function I'm using

```
function UpdateScore(snakes) //Updates the scores
{
    $("LeaderBoardList").empty();

    for (i in snakes) { //For each instance of snake
         var CurrentSnake = snakes[i]; //Make that the current snake
    var CurrentPlayerID = CurrentSnake.PlayerID; //make their id the current ID

    if (CurrentPlayerID == PlayerID) //Current player has special css for displaying score
    {
        var thisPlayerName = "<h4 class='PlayerScore'>Player " + CurrentPlayerID + "</h3>";
    } else //Different class for other players
    {
        var thisPlayerName = "<h4 class='EnemyScore'>Player " + CurrentPlayerID + "</h3>";
    }

    thisPlayerName += "<h4 class = 'Scores'> Kills: " + CurrentSnake.Kills + ' Score: ' + CurrentSnake.Score + '</h4>'

    $('#LeaderBoardList').append(thisPlayerName); //Show a line for each player

}
```

}

I first thought it was because this function is called a lot of times very fast so I added code to clear the list but that didn't help

I just tested this with me playing and its running an infinite loops, pic [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc9Aq.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
thisPlayerName += "<h4 class = 'Scores'> Kills: " + CurrentSnake.Kills + ' Score: ' + CurrentSnake.Score + '</h4>'
```

To

```
thisPlayerName = "<h4 class = 'Scores'> Kills: " + CurrentSnake.Kills + ' Score: ' + CurrentSnake.Score + '</h4>'
```

(remove the + from +=)